# What could prevent multi-touch functionality from working on a real iPhone when it works in the simulator?

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, multi-touch, zooming, panning

I have written an iPhone/iPad application in XCode. When I run it in the simulator, multi-touch functionality works exactly as expected.

But for some reason, multi-touch is not working on the real iPhone or iPad devices.

What could the problem be, and where should I start looking to debug it?

Comment: What is "not working"? Are you sure your devices aren't faulty?

Comment: when code works in the simulator and not on the device the first place to look is FileNames. Because FileName and filename are the same on most of the Macs running iphone simulator, but they are different on the real device. So if "not working" means it doesn't show the images you want then look at your filenames.

Comment: yes .. i'm sure tat device is absolutely fine as the inbuilt applications [like photo viewer] or images , i can perform pinch in and pinch out operations. But i'm not able to debug as its working fine in simulator but not on iPhone/iPad devices :( i ve deployed on both the devices but it failed to show the multi touch feature :(